# Matlab: Why is my plot not converging?

Tags: matlab, plot

Would you be able to help me to understand why the plot does not converge? What am I missing from the code? I am plotting mean and variance against number of trials. Thx

```
samplesize = 10;
trialsize = 1000;

firstvector = [1:trialsize];
vectorB = zeroes(trialsize,1);
vectorC = zeroes(trialsize,1)

for i=1:trialsize
   v1 = rand(samplesize, 1)
   vectorB(i) = mean(v1);
   vectorC(i) = var(v1);
end

plot(firstvector,vectorB)
plot(firstvector,vectorC)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to converge, and why?

Comment: I am expecting the plot to converge but it isnt, it is just a bunch of data with no trend.  How can I make it converge? I am running the trial many times with the goal of converging.  Thx

Comment: Of course it doesn't have any trend - you're just running the same trial over and over without keeping any data. You probably want to accumulate all the random samples and calculate the mean over all samples *so far*, not just the ten you just calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to do?  Basically take the mean and var of 10 more samples at a time?  So 1st loop take 10, next 20, next 30 .... 1000 times?

Before you where just taking the mean and var of 10 random samples at a time so ... you were never going to converge.

```
samplesize = 10;
trialsize = 1000;

firstvector = [1:trialsize];
vectorB = zeros(trialsize,1);
vectorC = zeros(trialsize,1);
v1 = rand(trialsize*samplesize, 1);
for i=1:trialsize
   vectorB(i) = mean(v1(1:i*samplesize));
   vectorC(i) = var(v1(1:i*samplesize));
end

subplot(2,1,1);plot(firstvector,vectorB)
subplot(2,1,2);plot(firstvector,vectorC)
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: yes, that is what i am looking for.  Thx What are you doing here mean(v1(1:i*samplesize));   I want to understand

Comment: I am just grabbing progressively larger chunks of 'v1'.  So first iteration of the loop 'i = 1' so you get  'v1(1:1*10)' or v(1:10) .  Next 'i =2' so you get v1(1:20) , then v(1:30) ... So you are taking the mean /var of the first 10, then 20, then 30 ... samples

Comment: so that is really the expected value and expected variances of the mean?.  , i think i understand now, thank you aero engy and nkjt!!